# QT drawing is not showing properly on different linux Machine

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5

My QT application(developed in Qt5.7.1) having some graphics and openGL drawings.

In two linux machine with ubuntu installed its working fine but on newly installed machine some of the buttons drawn using QGraphics got misplaced.

Both hardware is same i915 and modinfo i915 shows same result.
I have a doubt that whether I missed some graphics driver in new machine, How can I find the real issue. Please help

[image: Image of misplaced buttons]

[image: Working Copy]

Working Machine

```
lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Not Working Machine

```
lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 82Q33 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:26 memory:fdf00000-fdf7ffff ioport:ff00(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fdc00000-fdcfffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Comment: Please clarify which exact Version of Qt you are using and modify your Tags accordingly. If this is a bug in Qt the exact Version is important.